# How can I do the equivalent cURL/mimetype code in Java?

Tags: java, php, curl

I have this currently in PHP and was wondering what the equivalent would be in Java.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $vals[$index["CM:URL"][0]]["attributes"]["VALUE"]);
header("Content-type: " . $vals[$index["CM:RESOURCEOBJECT"][0]]["attributes"]["MIMETYPE"]);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) for the curl part.

With [HttpServletResponse.addHeader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/index.html), you can send your `Content-type` header.